# i want to know how to get the values based on id from Database by using spring boot in angular 4?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-module

I am using angular 4 and spring boot, when I click the module in angular form,`id` is sent to the spring boot to the database, I want to know how to get the values based on `id` from Database by using spring boot.

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component,OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { TreeViewComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-navigations';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {moduleService} from '../checkboxes/checkboxes.services';
import {providers} from 'ng2-toasty';
import {Module} from '../checkboxes/checkboxes';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-checkboxes',   
    templateUrl: './checkboxes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./checkboxes.component.css'],
    providers: [moduleService]
})
export class CheckboxesComponent  implements OnInit {

    @Input() moduleID: Module;

    myForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private module: moduleService) {
        let rolename = new FormControl();
        let status=new FormControl();
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            rolename : rolename,
            status : status
        });
    }        
    ngOnInit(){       
        this.module.createModule(this.moduleID.RoleId);      
        console.log(this.moduleID);
    }
    public countries: Object[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Australia', hasChild: true, expanded: true },
        { id: 2, pid: 1, name: 'New South Wales', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, pid: 1, name: 'Victoria' },
        { id: 4, pid: 1, name: 'South Australia' },
        { id: 6, pid: 1, name: 'Western Australia', isChecked: true },                
    ];   

    public field: Object = {
        dataSource: this.countries,
        id: 'id',
        parentID: 'pid',
        text: 'name',
        hasChildren: 'hasChild'
    };   
    public showCheckBox: boolean = true;
}
```

**service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Module} from '../checkboxes/checkboxes';
@Injectable()
export class moduleService {
  handleError: any;
  private moduleUrl = '/api/lodmodule';
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  createModule(id: number) {
      let head = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      this.http.post(this.moduleUrl, id, {headers: head}).map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
        () => {console.log(id)}
        );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you require your Angular controller to interact with db so go through this url [connect your db services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/AngularJS/152308/)

Comment: i have understood this and i want know how do this with angular 4?